# TFS Bug template + Adding custom fields

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I am trying to add custom field to a bug in TFS.
I opened the **Bug Work Item Type** but i have to enter the RefName as show in the image below.
Does any body know how can create Custom RefName

[image]

I tried to do as Ewald Hofman said, i got the below error[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just enter a name. It is used as the identifier for the column in the rest of the work item and in the warehouse.

A possible format is YourCompanyName.Category.FieldName

Comment: Don't use the brackets.  Example:  YourCompanyName.Ticket.BugPriority

Comment: Sorry: I should have more clear that the brackets were 'variables' :(. Edited the Answer